# Why encoded data is changed when retrieve from the database

Tags: python, mysql, encryption

I am having a problem with data corruption. I save the data after encripting in to a dabase. But when compare the same data after retriving, I found that value is not equal.

For me it seems, data is changed after saving data.

```
    RPasswd = "pw2013"
    Passwd = "2password"
    TVkey = hashlib.sha256(Passwd).digest()
    #encode password for before encryption to remove special characters
    Rencoded = base64.b64encode(RPasswd)
    #pad the length to a multiple of 16 with a space character for encryption
    Rencoded += ((16 - len(Rencoded)%16) * " ")
    #encrypt password to be stored as the user's credentials
    encRPasswd = AES.new(TVkey, AES.MODE_ECB).encrypt(Rencoded)

    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","db" )

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("select `group_id`, `group`, `password` from db.groups where group_id = 1 ")
        #print "number of rows" + cursor.rowcount
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in results:
            print row[0] 
            print row[1]
            pw = row[2]   

        print "test"
        db.commit()
    except:

        db.rollback()


    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
    if encRPasswd == pw:
        print "samme"
    else:
        print "not same"
```

When I run the code I get not same. Ideally, both values should be same.

Any hint?

Comment: I'm not seeing where you write the data in your example. What's the structure of the table? Also, *please* understand that a simple `sha256` (or the weird sha+encrypt you have) is *NOT* a secure way to store a password; use something like `bcrypt`, or better, understand [this explanation](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) (especially see "Conclusion" and "Good Password Hashing Functions")

Comment: I have already inserted the data to the table. I try to get the same data from the table and compare it. Problem is debuger shows some extra characters attached to pw value.